# How to feed a single tweet to a classifier model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, classification, tweepy

I'm writing a python code that involves analyzing a dataset using natural language processing and validating a twitter update . My Random forest model is working perfectly.

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('bully.txt', delimiter ='\t', quoting = 3)

corpus = []
for i in range(0,8576):
    tweet = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', dataset['tweet'][i])
    tweet = tweet.lower()
    tweet = tweet.split()
    ps = PorterStemmer()
    tweet = [ps.stem(word) for word in tweet if not word in 
 set(stopwords.words('english'))]
    tweet = ' '.join(tweet)
    corpus.append(tweet)
```

Converting dataset to vector

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer(max_features = 10000)
X = cv.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()
y = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values
```

Split into Train and Test data

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.20, random_state = 0)
```

Classifier model

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
classifier = RandomForestClassifier()
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

This is my code to access the tweets:

```
for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.home_timeline).items(1):
    print "tweet: "+ status.text.encode('utf-8')
    corpus1 = []
    update = status.text
    update = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', update)
    update = update.lower()
    update = update.split()
    ps = PorterStemmer()
    update = [ps.stem(word) for word in update if not word in set(stopwords.words('english'))]
    update = ' '.join(update)
    corpus1.append(update)
```

When I try to classify the extracted twitter update using the model:

```
if classifier.predict(update):
    print "bullying"

else:
    print "not bullying"
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: dude
```

How to feed a single tweet to the model?

My data set is this: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BG3cFszsZjAJ_pcST2jRxDH0ukf411M-

Comment: Is the word dude, for instance, in the lexicon of the original training set?

Comment: (New words might force you to retrain or treat them as unknown in some way)

Comment: No, dude is the first word of the tweet. If I convert the single tweet to vector and give it a label as 0(bullying) or 1(not bullying), and feed it to the classifier, the output comes same as the label I gave.

Answer (score 0):

You are use the CountVectorizer to convert your text data into an array of numbers where the rows indicate the document and the columns indicate the word. So, this would mean your model takes in an array of numbers as input. If you try to predict a with a string directly, the model does not know how to interpret it.

To tackle this, you need to transform your string which is understandable by your model.

```
update=cv.transform([update])
if classifier.predict(update):
    print "bullying"

else:
    print "not bullying"
```

CountVectorizer does not take a string objects directly, so, a list of that item is passed.